# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, c#-3.0, facebook-c#-sdk

```
        //Declaring of "Total Statements"
        double   NetSalary, PensionFundPercentage, grossSalary, TaxableAmount, MonthlySalary, Allowance, Paye, Uif, MedicalAid, totalDeduction;
        double PensionFund;


        double Other = 0;
        double.TryParse(txtOtherDeductions.Text, out Other);

        //Convert Statements
        Allowance = Convert.ToDouble(txtDeductions.Text);
        PensionFund = Convert.ToDouble(txtPenFund.Text);
        Paye = Convert.ToDouble(txtPayasUEarn.Text);
```

[image]
 IM UNABLE TO CALCULTE THE SALARY AMOUNT TO AGAINST THE THE AMOUNT QUOTED

Comment: The error is very clear and the exception line gives you all the info you need, the value of `txtPenFund.Text` cannot be parsed as a double.

Comment: What is the value txtPenFund.Text conatins? the error saying it contains other than numaric

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: @Ram the value is a number imported from sql database

Comment: you are probably facing a regional condition. you maybe have a decimal with comma and the framework is expecting a dot

Comment: @NicoRiff I tried that, it didnt work.

Comment: As @ram asked you, did you check the value of txtPenFund.Text? You can write a sample application and test with the value you are seeing here... I believe that is more easy.

Comment: yeah the is 2 @Shankar

Answer (score 0):

Try localize the where it fails.

*Taken from msdn.*

***Remarks***

*Using the ToDouble(String) method is equivalent to passing value to the Double.Parse(String) method. value is interpreted by using the formatting conventions of the current thread culture.*

*If you prefer not to handle an exception if the conversion fails, you can call the Double.TryParse method instead. It returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the conversion succeeded or failed.*

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, try using NumberFormatInfo while calling Convert.ToDouble(...).
I assume NumberFormat (or lack of) it could be a reason.
For example,

```
txtPenFund.Text = "2.00,00"; // assuming a convenient example to get exception
double PensionFund;
PensionFund = Convert.ToDouble(txtPenFund.Text); // will throw format exception
```

If I use NumberFormatInfo, I can convert the string to double as expected.

```
NumberFormatInfo numFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
numFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
numFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
// somewhere in the UI, txtPenFund is set
txtPenFund.Text = "2.00,00";

double PensionFund;
PensionFund = Convert.ToDouble(txtPenFund.Text, numFormat);
```